# How to prevent an account from downloading in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet, download, user-accounts

Is there a way to prevent accounts from downloading files in Windows 7?

Comment: Happy to accept Wil's answer below as I am happy to have only Internet Explorer on the machine.

Comment: Update: have just found that Windows Live Family Safety lets you block downloads for accounts that it monitors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and No.

You can prevent this in `Internet Explorer` by going to `Control Panel` or `Tools` menu, then  `Internet Options`.

Go to the `Security` Tab and under `Internet` choose `Custom Level`.

From here, you can disable `File Download`

[image]

However, this can easily be overwritten by someone who knows what they are doing, you may want to consider locking down the machine through Group Policy if on a domain or the Local Security policy otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Wil, that would be just perfect. How could I prevent this being overwritten using Local Security Policy?

Comment: @Sean Kearon - without the whole user being locked down, it will still be possible to overwrite this restriction, however, the easiest guide I can show you is this - http://malektips.com/internet_explorer_7_0037.html

Comment: Wil - you're a star, much appreciated :)